# Handling Undefined Property

Tags: javascript, undefined

I have an object that returns properties that are either `defined` or `undefined`.

I wish to handle these `undefined` properties but I keep getting an error of undefined. The following two code snippets below are what I have tried so far:

```
if (typeof choice.Location == "undefined") {
}
```

and

```
if (choice.Location == undefined) {

}
```

Edit:

To clarify, if I do something like this.

```
if (typeof choice == "undefined") {
}
else if (choice.Location) {
//do something 
}
```

I get the same error.

Comment: If you're getting that error, it's probably that `choice` itself is `undefined`.  What **exactly** does the error say?

Comment: Sure, It says "Cannot read property Location of undefined".

Comment: then choice must be undefined. please check it in developer tool

Comment: `if (typeof choice == "undefined") {`

Comment: So you're trying to get the property `Location` of something that is undefined.

Comment: better, you can check like this way if(choice && choice.location)

Comment: Right then, `choice` is the problem. You have not posted enough code for the actual cause of that to be apparent to anyone.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Comment: If I put something like if (choice == "undefined") {} the code will go to the next part of the statement but still throw the Location error.

Comment: You're only checking to see if it's undefined - you're not doing anything if it's not so your code will continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for both the object and then it's property.

Something simple like the following would do it:

```
if (typeof choice !== 'undefined' && choice.location) { ... }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It gives me the same error.

Comment: @sacora  If you want help then please read how to create a **[mcve]**.  You must post some code that we can run so that we can actually see the problem, because the answers you have been given *are correct*, so your question must be wrong.  Until we can reproduce the problem then you have not asked a valid question.  Please don't reply to this comment.  Just digest, read the link I've given you, and then fix the question or ask a new one.

Comment: I agree with Archer but i've updated my answer to include a typeof comparison. I'm not sure what you are trying to do exactly, but this solution should work for most cases

Comment: If my updated answer works for you, do you mind accepting it please?